# OpeCV count people in a room

Tags: c++, opencv

I need guidance in order to achieve a code. The purpose is to count the number of students that are there in a study room. My idea is:

1) take a picture empty classroom study
2) take a picture at a time of day with the students seated in the predetermined places, because the chairs can not be movable.
3) Define the key points in the picture corresponding to the seats classroom study.
4) Difference of two photos.
5) if these posts are now occupied (the difference has given a visible outcome) then count the number of difference that corresponds to the number of students.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement it in code?

```
Mat differenceFrame(Mat prev_frame, Mat curr_frame); 



int main(void) {

    cv::Mat frame, frame1, framedifference;
    int key = 0;

    frame = imread("2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

        frame1 = imread("1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    while (key != 27){
        differenceFrame(frame, frame1);

        cv::absdiff(frame, frame1, framedifference);  

        key = 0;
        cv::imshow("stream", framedifference);
        key = cv::waitKey(10);
    }


                ContPeople(framedifference)  ?????

}
```

NOW:
I tried this solution. I do not know if it is the most efficient. The blob could help me?
When I make the difference of the image, some reflective points me marks them as if they were changed, I think that's a problem of too much light, you can refine the difference avoiding these problems?

cv::Mat imgFrame1Copy = F_RoomFull.clone();
    cv::Mat imgFrame2Copy = F_RoomEmpty.clone();

```
cv::Mat imgDifference;
cv::Mat imgThresh;

cv::cvtColor(imgFrame1Copy, imgFrame1Copy, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::cvtColor(imgFrame2Copy, imgFrame2Copy, CV_BGR2GRAY);

cv::GaussianBlur(imgFrame1Copy, imgFrame1Copy, cv::Size(5, 5), 0);
cv::GaussianBlur(imgFrame2Copy, imgFrame2Copy, cv::Size(5, 5), 0);

cv::absdiff(imgFrame1Copy, imgFrame2Copy, imgDifference);

cv::threshold(imgDifference, imgThresh, 180, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

cv::imshow("imgThresh", imgThresh);

cv::Mat structuringElement3x3 = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3));
cv::Mat structuringElement5x5 = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5));
cv::Mat structuringElement7x7 = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(7, 7));
cv::Mat structuringElement9x9 = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(9, 9));

cv::dilate(imgThresh, imgThresh, structuringElement5x5);
cv::dilate(imgThresh, imgThresh, structuringElement5x5);
cv::erode(imgThresh, imgThresh, structuringElement5x5);

cv::Mat imgThreshCopy = imgThresh.clone();


cv::findContours(imgThreshCopy, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
cv::Mat imgContours(imgThresh.size(), CV_8UC3, SCALAR_BLACK);
cv::drawContours(imgContours, contours, -1, SCALAR_WHITE, -1);
cv::imshow("imgContours", imgContours);


printf("%d", contours.size());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you subtract those two images (matrices), there will be nonzero values in the students' positions only. Other values should be zero or very close to zero.

Set a threshold to set all other values to zero (i mean if there is any nonzero small values in positions where there is no student in previous image).

Then do contour detection.
See the code here:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

The number of contours= no. of students

if two contours overlap, use contour area to count them. Expecting that maximum contours will be non-overlaping

Comment: unless students are hugging (contours overlap)

Comment: ha ha. They are sitting on different chairs i think

Comment: Even if some contours overlap, you can separate them using contour area. but if 3-5 groups of students (2/3/4 students in each group) are hugging each other , then it will be very complex situation. if 2 students or 3 students out of 20 are hugging each other, it should not be a problem

Comment: Ok, but since students are assumed to be in chairs the positioning of the camera is a good way simplify the imaging recognition problem.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that chairs are arranged in parallen lines and camera position is perpendicular to that line. The questioner didn't specify those things. So I assumed usual photography scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your concern.
The camera is positioned in such a way that the contours do not join. The chairs are fixed, so students can not position themselves where they want. I just need to evaluate, in the point where I want to, if these points have been the difference or not.


Now I look at the code for the contours. However how can I do a search in the areas of the image? how can I say, in that the pixels around There has been no difference?

Comment: as they are same image, if you subtract two images, you will get 0 except the student positions. then you can use contour detection.

Comment: I improved the code and modified the main post, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Background Subtraction method in OpenCv. There are a lot of parameters that allow fine tuning.

Here is the link [Link](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html#gsc.tab=0)